# Websocket handshake Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value is incorrect

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

I'm writing a c++ websocket server, dev tools on chrome says sec-websocket-accept header value is incorrect. I've tested for days and it all seems fine. The client closes with readystate 3 without the websocket onopen being called although it shows as 101 in chrome dev tools.

This is my code for calculating the keys

```
string magickey = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
string key = msgkey.append(magickey);

unsigned char* sha_str = SHA1(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length(), nullptr);
string acceptkey = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(sha_str), strlen((char*)sha_str));

string handshake_response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
handshake_response.append("Upgrade: websocket\r\n");
handshake_response.append("Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
handshake_response.append("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "+acceptkey+"\r\n");
handshake_response.append("\r\n");
```

Chrome Response

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols  
Upgrade: websocket  
Connection: Upgrade  
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 5T5MvxP1iz40vLpi3kQs/ifDaCo=
```

Chrome Request

```
GET ws://localhost:4897/echo HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:4897  
Connection: Upgrade  
Pragma: no-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
Upgrade: websocket  
Origin: http://localhost  
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8  
Sec-WebSocket-Key: LKF8lHGznbKGIgO1UzAOhg==  
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

It says "Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value".

Chrome also shows one additional frame received size 79 bytes opcode -1.

Thanks Heaps!

Comment: What is the value of `acceptkey` ?

Comment: thanks, i've listed the key values in the question

Comment: Have you tried with `\n` instead of `\r\n` ? Also, order of lines seem different in the Chrome output (from your code).

Comment: yes \n does the exact same, I've also edited chrome output to actual headers instead of parsed.

Comment: i'm using windows 8 so /r/n should be correct.

Comment: And what is the value of `msgkey` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome says that 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' is incorrect. Trying to compute it manually, I have to agree with Chrome.

My test:

1. concat "LKF8lHGznbKGIgO1UzAOhg==" and "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
   => "LKF8lHGznbKGIgO1UzAOhg==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", that's `key`.
2. compute SHA1 160 bits hex: **bf15 14e3 7108 0ee4 7782 c709 a767 cc72 423d e5c4**
3. From your log, your encoding to base64 is: 5T5MvxP1iz40vLpi3kQs/ifDaCo=
4. Decoding it to hex: **e53e 4cbf 13f5 8b3e 34bc ba62 de44 2cfe
   27c3 682a**

The bold values should be equal. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Possible problems:

- Is `sha_str` null-terminated ? i.e. `strlen((char*)sha_str) == 20` ?
- signed/unsigned char mixup ?

Comment: aha, I found the issue was a leading space in the original key so the SHA1 was incorrect as you pointed out, socket is open, woohoo! thank you so much.